# Ruby FFI gem fail to open dynamic library

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am trying to create a dynamic library inside a ruby module by using ffi_lib and providing the name of the library (.dll file), FFI executes the function "ffi_lib" in library.rb file but is failing when executes the following section:

```
lib = FFI::DynamicLibrary.open(libname, lib_flags)
```

With the error:
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2-x64-mingw32/lib/ffi/library.rb:145:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'dummy.dll':  (LoadError)

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I was using a 32-bit .dll in a 64-bit setup. Compiled the dll for 64 and now it works.